# trouble sharing on Pinterest - "schedule" word keeps showing up

Tags: pinterest, squarespace, social-media

When I manually post a photo with my blog url the word "Schedule" appears in the description on Pinterest. I've tried debugging the url in Pinterest but it comes back with a 429 error. This word shows up a lot on my blogs. I found "Schedule"  in the blog excerpt, but even after deleting it, it either comes back in the excerpt or still shows up in the description.
**Pinterest support says Issue is on Squarespace's side. While inspecting source code, the word "schedule" is embedded within Squarespace's "data-name" tag:
Static.SQUARESPACE_CONTEXT
I would recommend that you loop in a web developer to help remove that code.**

How do I do that and would that fix the problem? 
Thanks,
Michelle

Comment: Is your blog named schedule?

Squarespace customer support can be reached here –support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/requests